# Insert ads in wp taxonomy is not working

Tags: wordpress, function, ads

I'm tryng to insert ads after each 3,6,9 specific tag I added in a listing, using this function:
(Code edited with get the content)

```
 add_filter( 'get_the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads2' );
function prefix_insert_post_ads2( $content ) {
    //The last condition here ensures that ads are only added to posts
     if ( is_archive()) {
        return prefix_insert_ads( $content );
    }

    return $content;
}

function prefix_insert_ads( $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</em>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
        $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        if ( in_array($index, array(3, 6, 9)) ) {
            //Replace the html here with a valid version of your ad code
            $paragraphs[$index] .= '<div>Ad goes here</div>';
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

But is not working in the taxonomy listing, I tried  with if is archive, if is tax, if is archive, if has term, even if is paged!, but is not working at all. But weirdly enough works in another listing which is in a page. Is a wp Events Manager plugin taxonomy, maybe I need to create a placeholder ¿?, I have no clue why is not working. Any ideas?

UPDATED:

I'm using this function now and is not working either:

```
//Insert ads 


 function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ads, $content ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $ads ) ) {
        return $content;
    }

    $closing_p = '</em>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );

    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }

        $n = $index + 1;
        if ( isset( $ads[ $n ] ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $ads[ $n ];
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_ads' );
function prefix_insert_ads( $content ) {
    if ( is_archive() && ! is_admin() ) {
        $content = prefix_insert_after_paragraph( array(
            '3' => '<div>1</div>',
            '6' => '<div>2</div>',
            '9' => '<div>3</div>',
        ), $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: There is two method get_the_content and the_content for fetch the content. Now you have set filter for the_content only  so add one more filter of get the content and than please check

Comment: Thanks, tried with the_content and get_the_content and both, doesn't work. This is the [link](https://calendar.powwows.com/events/categories/pow-wows/pow-wows-in-alabama/)

Comment: can you update the code what you tried in get content filter

Comment: Have you confirmed your `prefix_insert_ads()` function is being called? Are you sure it is the conditional that is not working?

Comment: @Aki, code is updated, using both the content and get the content, maybe I can try with get the content only.

Comment: @Chris yes, the function is ok, I have one similar (with different html tag and different conditional and is working, in a page with listing). I have no clue why is not working. Maybe I need to find another way, can't be with a loop because the loop is managed by the plugin and I don't want to edit the plugin main files.

Comment: are you calling the   the_content() directly in the page.php or you are running this function in the loop of while?

Comment: is in functions.php, the loops are managed by Event Manager plugin, in the main plugin files, not templates, I can't modify the loop directly.  In the listings that are in a regular page the function works fine in the taxonomy pages is not working and now I just checked and doesn't work in the search results either.